# New getExternalFilesDir in Android R crashes in emulator because SD card is missing?

Tags: android, android-file

I'm trying to use non-deprecated methods for storing an image. However, the suggested `context.getExternalFilesDir` crashes in the emulator on the first line in the following.

```kotlin
val albumFolder = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)!!
i { "Writing file to ${albumFolder.absolutePath} "}
albumFolder.mkdirs()
check(albumFolder.exists() && albumFolder.canWrite()) { "Missing or non-writable folder: ${albumFolder.absolutePath}"}
```

It throws 2 errors, then dies on a NPE for the first line.

```
E/vold: Failed to find mounted volume for /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MYAPP/files/Pictures/
W/ContextImpl: Failed to ensure /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MYAPP/files/Pictures: android.os.ServiceSpecificException:  (code -22)
```

Comment: please check the following two links  about scoped storage. You have to use Scoped storage feature after Android 10 or higher version. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/storage

Comment: I thought I was - https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific#media says to use `context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)`